# Error on save file to desktop user with name + data and time

Tags: vb.net

I try to save my file with a special name "MDlabs" + data and time in my vb.net project
What i try to do is to save the file like this MDlabs_yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.jpg
But it give me a error
This is The Error

> {"The specified path format is not supported."}

This is my code

```
Dim mydataandtimeforsave = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
    PB1.Save(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop + "\MDAL1Image_" + mydataandtimeforsave + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
```

Comment: "/" is an illegal filename character.

Comment: Do you really need delimiters at all for the date and time?  I usually just use "yyyyMMddHHmmss" in file and folder names.

Comment: @video.baba tank you for replay well i have try DateTime.Now but i have the same error Because the objective is to give a new name each time i save so like that i can be sure not have the same name on rhe photos i save , because if its there the same file the software will erase the old one

Comment: @video.baba Tank you like that its solved my problem how can i mark your comment like answer?

Comment: @bluemoonodd, I don't know how to mark as answer. maybe just upvote the comment? ;-)

Comment: @video.baba Really tank you for the help , i have no options here to vote on comments only on answer

Comment: @video.baba post your comment as an answer and let bluemoon odd accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are characters you cannot use in a file name. In this case where you have used the characters in your code you can use other characters such as `-` to separate the parts you're interested in. You can sanitize the filename as follows

```
Dim tempName = Date.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") ' Using your example but this could also come from user input.
Dim pattern = $"[{String.Join("", Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())}]" ' Assumes Imports System.IO at the top
Dim fileName = Regex.Replace(tempName, pattern, "-") ' Assumes Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions at the top
```

You can then save the whole file as follows...

```
PB1.Save(Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "MDAL1Image_", fileName & ".jpg"), ImageFormat.Bmp)
```

This way, you can replace any invalid characters with a dash and your files will save safely regardless of any unwanted characters the names contained.

Answer (score 0):

You could not use /: (some special characters)in your file names. Its a general restriction. Try other date formats